# How to print the webservice(jqurey) hit on the console for search functionality

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium2, browser-automation, javascript, selenium3

1. Open a website, press F12 go to network option and enable preserve log
2. now type the work you want to search eg:dogs
3. we can see the service "http://search.test.com/search........."

here i want the service displayed in the network to print in the selenium console and then get the JSON response of this service